# Replace the Post Excerpt Meta Box with a Field in My Custom Meta Box

Tags: metabox, excerpt

I've got a custom meta box for a custom post type which will be the only metabox I plan to show in the main column (except the native title box).  I want to move the native Expert box/field inside my Custom Meta Box.

I'm able to create a field called Excerpt in my Meta Box, however  I only know how to save this to the Custom Fields, not the original location that the native Except saves to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just name the field 'excerpt'.

E.g.:

```
<textarea name="excerpt" id="excerpt"><?php echo esc_html( '$post->post_excerpt' ); ?></textarea> <!-- if it is a textarea field -->
```

or

```
<input name="excerpt" id="excerpt" value="<?php echo esc_attr( '$post->post_excerpt' ); ?>" /> <!-- if it is a text field -->
```

Comment: Where can I find the documentation to do this with other metaboxes?  I guess I really only need to know the IDs of the other wordpress native metaboxes.

Comment: Nevermind, that was a silly question.  I just looked at the code in firebug and it was right there.

Answer (score 1):

This would be a function to update the post_excerpt with a field with the name 'my_custom_field'.

```
function my_custom_save_function($post_id){
    update_post(array('ID' => $post_id, 'post_excerpt' => $_POST['my_custom_field']));
}
add_action('save_post', 'my_custom_save_function');
```

Comment: I figured it would be done with a hook but I'm wondering why you prefer this approach to the one sorich suggested?  His seems a little lighter.

Comment: I prefer this way as it seens to me a much cleaner to me and its easier to extend. Normally you gonna add much more fields then just one and then you have to use this hook anyway.